# Python/Django logging with extra options

Tags: python, django, exception, logging

I have a logging config file in Django that takes `sys.exc_info()` tuple & passes them as extra options while logging (see the variables `type` & `value` in formatter below)

```
'formatters': {
    'basic': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(lineno)d %(message)s %(type)s %(value)s'
    },
},
```

Here's how I log the error:

```
    except Exception, e:
        extra = {'type':sys.exc_info()[0], 'value':sys.exc_info()[1]}
        logger.warning('My message', extra=extra)
```

However if I simply write

```
    except Exception, e:
        logger.warning('My message')
```

I get an exception because the variables `type` & `value` are undefined in formatter now. How can I tell the formatter to treat these variables as optional i.e. if I pass them while logging, then use them, else skip them.

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Added further update with `Filter` example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you *don't* pass the `exc_info` tuple parts explicitly in your logging calls. Instead, note that if an exception occurs and you pass `exc_info=True` or `exc_info=sys.exc_info()`, then the tuple is already stored in the `LogRecord`'s `exc_info` attribute. You can access these in your formatter, so you can either use a `Formatter` subclass or a `Filter` subclass to convert parts of the tuple to other `LogRecord` attributes which can be referred to in the format string (or even otherwise, handled by a custom `Formatter` subclass).

**Update:** You *can* reference as `%(exc_info)s` in the format string, but that will just display the tuple. Note that a `Formatter`'s `formatException` method can be overridden to display the exception. The default will format a standard traceback - do I understand that you *don't* want that to happen?

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatException(self, exc_info):
        return 'exception: %s %s' % exc_info[:2])
```

That would print a one-liner rather than a full traceback, but on a new line. Or you could use an approach like:

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        if isinstance(record.exc_info, tuple):
            record.exc_data = ' %s %s' % record.exc_info[:2]
        else:
            record.exc_data = ''
        return super(MyFormatter, self).format(record)

    def formatException(self, exc_info):
        return ''
```

and then use a format string with `%(exc_data)s` in it.

With both of these, you need to ensure that a true `exc_info` is passed into the logging call, to ensure that the exception data is saved in the `LogRecord`. The `exception()` method of loggers does this (with a level of `ERROR`).

**Further update:** To do this with a `Filter` subclass, you could do something like:

```
class MyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if isinstance(record.exc_info, tuple):
            record.exc_data = ' %s %s' % record.exc_info[:2]
        else:
            record.exc_data = ''
        # The next bit is to prevent the standard Formatter from writing
        # a traceback
        record.exc_info = None
        return True # otherwise, the record doesn't get output
```

This should have the same effect as the earlier example, so you can use the same format string.

Comment: This sounds like an approach worth exploring. (1) Should I access `exc_info` in formatter as `%(exc_info)s`?  (2) Could you show an example of how to extract `exc_info[0]` inside formatter.  -- P.S. python docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes says `You shouldn’t need to format this yourself` for `exc_info`

Comment: Good learning. Thanks. Could you also point to an example of using the `Filter` subclass.